# Does sharing a Hyper-V host USB device with guest VM via enhanced session require constant connection?

Tags: usb, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a requirement to attach a USB device to a hyper-v host, and get it connected to a guest VM.

Looks like there are hardware solutions, or software solutions cost over $100, but the only free/opensource thing I can find is USB/IP. This seems to have been ditched as last update was 2011, and only a Linux server app was built, so wouldn't fit my scenario.

I saw some mention of using enhanced sessions, but I tried briefly with an iPhone and this did not seem to appear. In addition, I assume it requires me to have a constant enhanced session window connected to a VM (which in itself I would expect to be a security concern), and it must also mean that if the host restarts, the connection needs to be restored manually?

So my question is, if I pass through a host USB device via an enhanced session, does it:

1. Require a constant enhanced session window to be running with a user logged in via that session
2. Require you to manually restart the enhanced session if the host restarts

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Can I amend my question to be specifically about the enhanced session part of my question?

Comment: Of course you can. After any edits your question will go into a queue where we can vote to reopen.

Comment: If you're using an RDP session it will have to be constantly connected for the device to be connected. In addition it would have to be established from the computer that has the USB device attached. See also [Use local resources on Hyper-V virtual machine with VMConnect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/use-local-resources-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-vmconnect)

Comment: God that's such an awful experience. Guess I don't have any option without a switch the ESXi. Thanks for confirming.